# World language in Italian

Tags: translation, vocabulary

What would you call a world language in Italian?

Google definition: "a language known or spoken in many countries."

World languages are English, Spanish, French.

*There seems to be a second definition: "an artificial language for international use." But that is not what I mean.

I think that the one that I do NOT mean is this: lingua universale, lingua internazionale.

But I am looking for translation of the first meaning ("a language known or spoken in many countries.").

Thank you.

Comment: Just to understand better: why is it that *lingua universale* and *lingua internazionale* don't work for you?

Comment: @DaG because I saw its definition on Google, according to what is written there they both refer to an artifitial language, like esperanto

Comment: Fine, thanks. Indeed, one would probably think of artificial languages, but not necessarily. Do you happen to remember where do these definitions come from? (Google itself is just a search engine, it refers you to dictionaries or other reference works.)

Answer (score 4):

I offer two possible ways of saying something close to what you are looking for.

One is **lingua [veicolare](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/veicolare1/)**, a language used to work, teach, make business among people of different mother tongues, said especially, as you remark, of English, Spanish, French.

Slightly different is **[lingua franca](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/lingua-franca/)**, which originally referred to a specific mixed language used to communicate across the Mediterranean, and nowadays is used in general for a language more than a community understand and use to communicate, but mostly for pidgins, Creoles and so on.

Comment: Could I use: una lingua diffusa a livello mondiale?

Comment: Yes, that would be fine, @cornejo.